# Windows authentication issue on local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022, windows-authentication, iis-express, impersonation

I created an ASP.NET MVC application and then enabled the Windows Authentication. In that, I have used the Entity Framework database first approach model to connect to the SQL database.

After that, I added simple logic to fetch the data from the database and then display it on the UI.

This is the web.config file configuration for database connection string and windows authentication.

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DemoModel.csdl|res://*/DemoModel.ssdl|res://*/DemoModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxx;initial catalog=xxxx;Integrated Security = True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms defaultUrl="~\demo\Home\Index" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Base/PageNotFound"/>
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" password="" userName=""/>
  </system.web>
```

When I try to run an application on my local machine, it shows an authentication popup, but even after entering the proper username and password, it keeps on coming.

After I did some research and analysis, I commented the below impersonate attribute of the identity configuration element in the web.config file. Then I tried to run the application on my local machine. It worked as expected.

```
<!--<identity impersonate="true" password="" userName=""/>-->
```

Note: The same application I have deployed in IIS with the impersonate attribute is true in the web.config file, there it works as expected.

Can you please tell me the reason why the application is working without impersonate attribute in the web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the account that you are using to impersonate does not have access to the directory on the file system where your website is located.

Is there a reason you want to use impersonation? It is different and separate from Windows Authentication. You can use Windows Authentication without impersonation, and you can use impersonation without Windows Authentication. Impersonation allows your application to do other things (like access files) using the credentials of the impersonated account.

Without impersonation, your website runs with the default IIS credentials (in IIS) or your own user account (in IIS Express).

Comment: I am using the impersonation because in the application there is logic to access files. One thing, on IIS, I have enabled both Windows and Impersonation authentication, then it worked. But when I try to run the application on a local machine with impersonate and windows authentication, then I'm not able to login with windows credentials. But if I remove the impersonation from the web.config, then it will work on a local machine.

Comment: Right. So on your local machine, does the account you're using to authenticate to the website have access to the folder where the website files are?

Comment: Yes, I have the admin access on my local machine.

Comment: Without admin access, I am not able to login into the application using my windows credentials even though I disabled impersonate authentication in the web.config file.